# Open google maps activity from my application and if user reaches the destination redirect the user to my app

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to open google maps turn by turn direction screen on button click and  want to check if user reaches the destination redirect the user to my app currently i am using this code to open google maps

```
            String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:0,0?q="+ destinationLoc.latitude+","+destinationLoc.longitude
                    + "(The Embroidery Store)" );
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

I want to redirect the user to my app after he reaches the destination.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the concept of geo-fencing. 
The following links might help:
https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Geofencing